# Android TextView Text Auto fit

Tags: java, android, textview

I have found a solution to fit text inside a TextView at [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/17782522#17782522).
However, my solution doesn't seem to work.

Here is my xml:

```
<parkpurdue.parkpurdue.AutoResizeTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Park @ Purdue"
    android:layout_weight="1.6"
    android:background="#3366FF"
    android:id="@+id/parkAtPurdue"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

And here is my java code:

```
TextView topText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parkAtPurdue);
topText.setText("Park at Purdue");
```

I tried changing the java code to this as well:

```
AutoResizeTextView topText = new AutoResizeTextView(getApplicationContext());
topText = (AutoResizeTextView) findViewById(R.id.parkAtPurdue);
topText.setText("Park at Purdue");
```

I tried calling the topText.resize() function as well. No apparent results were found. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
AutoResizeTextView topText = (AutoResizeTextView) findViewById(R.id.parkAtPurdue);
topText.setText("Park at Purdue");
```

Comment: Tried that, with no results.

Comment: OK, need more info then, what you have looks fine.  Include logcat for starters, and more details about your problem.

Comment: I don't have anything in logcat. What other kinds of details are you needing?